# Create and execute a LINQPad class/method in separate AppDomain

Tags: appdomain, linqpad

I'm trying to prototype some code in everyone's favorite prototyping IDE (LINQPad).  I want to run a class I've created in the script in a separate AppDomain.  For example:

```
void Main()
{
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
    var qry = (AdHocQuery)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap( typeof( AdHocQuery ).Assembly.Location, typeof( AdHocQuery ).FullName );
    qry.Run();

    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
}

class AdHocQuery
{
    public void Run()
    {
    }
}
```

I get the following exception: `FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\\Users\\terry.aney\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\LINQPad5\\_jpomhdlf\\query_onuisp.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`

Is it possible to do this in LINQPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, even though it is from a tweet from Joe Albahari :)

> Given that you're specifying assembly location rather than name, use
> CreateInstance*From*AndUnwrap.  Also, use Util.CreateAppDomain instead
> of AppDomain.CreateDomain to make dependencies resolve. Add
> Util.NewProcess=true to query if you get type compatibility errors.